# Microscopic form of Ohm's law

Tags: electric-current, electric-fields, electrical-resistance

Microscopic form of Ohm's law is:
$$\vec j = \sigma \vec E$$
Where $\vec j$ and $\vec E$ is the electric density and electric field at a point on the conductor respectively. $\sigma$ is the conductance of the conductor.

Now my doubt is that if there can be no electric field within a conductor then how electric field within a conductor is defined in the microscopic form of the Ohm's law?

Comment: The rule that conductors are field free is only valid in the electrostatic case, not when there are moving charges.

Comment: @CuriousOne so you mean that if the electrons are flowing then there will be electric field inside a conductor? If it so then why we use the formula of electrostatic electric field, $V = E•d$ to derive the microscopic form of the Ohm's law? This electric field formula is for uniform electric field between two long metallic plates having positive and negative charges.

Comment: You can measure this easily with a voltmeter on a piece of wire. When there is current flow, there is a voltage drop, which means that there is an electric field (otherwise there could be no current flow!). If you want to do it on a three dimensional volume, mix some salt into water, hang two electrodes in there, attach a battery and then put your voltmeter leads anywhere in the liquid between the electrodes. You will find a voltage drop and an electric field. In the most general microscopic version of Ohm's law for anisotropic conductors, the conductivity is actually a tensor (aka matrix).

Comment: @CuriousOne Can you separate the effects of infinite conductivity from the effects of non-static fields?   I.e., can a perfect conductor support an internal field?  Is the field in a wire due to imperfect conductivity or dynamic charges?